# How to reset the bash completion after a parameter

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I'm creating a completion function (through `complete -F`) for a command which takes another command as trailing parameters. For example:

```
command exec -- another_command
```

Now I know I can match on the "exec --" part and return:

```
COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -c) )
```

which correctly gives the list of possible options. Unfortunately this does not work correctly for `another_command`'s arguments - I'm still running the `command` completion instead.

How can I completely reset the completion state at `exec --` and tell bash to reevaluate from there as if it was a new line?

Comment: https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/be906e813e5794876e7ac45e3fcd6a37b0bb8922/bash_completion#L2573 and you might want to reserach sudo completino